# Is it possible to rotate axes in 3D with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart, graphing

Is it possible to angle the axes of a chart in 3D? In particular, I'm working with createBarChart3D. The only configuration options are in the constructor of `BarRenderer3D` for x & y offsets. Web searches have only lead to questions about rotating the labels in 3D and consulting the API documentation for `CategoryAxis3D` and `NumberAxis3D`, I was unable to find any function for axis rotation.

This is what I have:
[image: 3D Bar Chart]

This is what I want:

[image: 3D Bar Chart Angled Axis]

How can this be done in JFreeChart?

Comment: See recent entries in this [forum thread](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21915).

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done in JFreeChart, which does not have a real 3D renderer (it just adds a 3D effect to 2D charts).  There is a new library (by the author of JFreeChart - a.k.a. me) called [Orson Charts 3D](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/) that will do what you are asking for.  It's not free like JFreeChart though.